# bootstrap tab doesn't switch on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://bootply.com/107403

the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.stat-wrap a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
    })
</script>
```

I've bind the correct link to id, but everything just showed up, nothing work. struggled for over 1 hour but didn't solve. help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example with your code: http://bootply.com/107407

The data-toggle="tab" attribute needs to be on the anchor, not on the div.

```
  <a href="#note-tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <div class="active">
          <div class="col-md-3 stat-text-wrap active">
              <p class="stat-number-desc">PRIVATE NOTES</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#quotes-tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <div>
          <div class="col-md-3 stat-text-wrap">
              <p class="stat-number-desc">QUOTES</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#project-tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <div>
          <div class="col-md-3 stat-text-wrap">
              <p class="stat-number-desc">PROJECTS DONE</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#skill-tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <div>
          <div class="col-md-3 stat-text-wrap">
              <p class="stat-number-desc">NEW SKILLS</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </a>
```

Also the tab content needs to be wrapped in a container with the class "tab-content".

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="note-tab">
      <input placeholder="NOTE What's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="quotes-tab">
      <input placeholder="QUOTE What's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="project-tab">
      <input placeholder="PROJECTWhat's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="skill-tab">
      <input placeholder="SKILLWhat's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use `data-toggle="tab"` with anchor tag i.e., `<a href="#note-tab">` like this" `<a href="#note-tab"  data-toggle="tab">`

Secondly wrap up your tabs content in `.tab-content` like this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="note-tab">
    <input placeholder="NOTE What's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="quotes-tab">
    <input placeholder="QUOTE What's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="project-tab">
    <input placeholder="PROJECTWhat's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="skill-tab">
    <input placeholder="SKILLWhat's on your mind?" class="status-input" type="text">
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Zeshan